# Problem to send emails using sendmail in ubuntu server

Tags: php, ubuntu, smtp, sendmail

I am trying to send emails in my server using sendmail. I have tried using mail function in php and from terminal: echo "Subject: Try" | sendmail example@gmail.com but I get some error messages when I look to mailq. It says "Deferred: Connection timed out with smtp.lg.ehu.eus" or "Deferred: alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.: No route to host".

[image]
I have internet conexion and I can ping smtp.gmail.com

These is the result of connecting to by telnet to smtp.lg.ehu.eus in port 25:
[image]

I would appreciate if you could help me

Comment: Can your server send **any** email? What software is it using? (actual sendmail, or exim/postfix/etc?) What is the complete error message from mailq? What is result of `telnet smtp.lg.ehu.eus 25`?

Comment: @jhnc No it can't send any email, the comand runs without errors but when I wait a bit and look to the mail queue teh errors appear. I am using actual sendmail. I edit the post and add photos of the full queue and the result of telnet to the smtp server.

Comment: Check your firewall settings and ensure outgoing to port 25 is allowed. Check that your service provider allows your machine to send email directly (some providers require use of their own [smarthost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_host)).

Comment: @jhnc I have checked and it seems that my isp blocks emails comming from port 25, I should use port 587. I have used this command to redirect the traffic from port 25 to 587: `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -dport 25 -j REDIRECT --to-port 587 ` but the error still appear

Comment: Don't use iptables; fix your sendmail configuration to use your ISP smarthost/port. You may also need to configure sendmail to use a username/password when it connects. Read your ISP's documentation on how to configure your server, or ask their technical support for instructions.